# AngularJS: break the connection between a form and its parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’m writing an application where I have a form and I have to POST the content of the form. For this, I have written this short function:

```
$scope.record = function (data_form, validation_control, validate) {
    var data = {};
    data_form.$getControls().forEach(function (control) {
        if (control.$valid) {
            data[control.$name] = control.$modelValue;
            control.$processModelValue(); // For normalization
        }
    });
    server_post(data).then(
        /* … */
    );
};
```

The form includes some “standard” inputs, but also some specially-crafted directives, with `ng-model` and `name`, that behave like complex inputs.

Unfortunately, those directives include some “standard” inputs in their templates. Then the values for those internal inputs show up in my `data` object.

I thought I could wrap those internal inputs in a child form that should be ignored by my `record` function. But the child form still shows up during the scan. Moreover, the validity of the child form affects that of the parent form.

Is there a way I can break the link between the child form and the parent form?

As an alternative, what would be a clean way to identify, during the scan, that a control is in fact a child form?

I tried:

```
        if (control.$valid && !(control instanceof data_form.constructor)) {
            /* … */
        }
```

but it failed because, apparently, `data_form.constructor` is `Object()`, so all controls are ignored. An as far as I can see, the `FormController` function is internal to AngularJS.

Or is there an alternative way to keep my “internal” inputs hidden from the form?

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to describe here;  without a [mcve] it may be difficult to help here.  Why are you trying to "scan" the form controls to "normalize" properties, instead of just binding your form elements to an object that you can directly work from?

Comment: @Claies: Thanks for the hint, I will try to improve my question. As for the “normalization” part, I should have removed that line from my code snippet; it is irrelevant here. As for your suggestion to bind the form elements to an object, that might have been the best way to design the app, but unfortunately that’s not how it was designed.